# Issues with creating file with 'npx-create-react-app'

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

`--> npx create-react-app my-app npx: installed 98 in 7.827s`

`EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/my-app'`

`--> cd my-app cd: no such file or directory: my-app`

When trying to get started, it doesn't seem to create an app. I had used npm create-react-app my-app before however global install are no longer supported. If I then `mkdir my-app`  it again says "**Read-only file system**"

Comment: where specifically are you trying to install? What is the full path?

Answer (score 1):

It seens like an issue with permission.  The directory where npx is trying to create a folder named my-app is in read only state. Try changing the permission.

if you are using lynux, you can try
sudo chmod -R 777 
The -R (or --recursive) options make it recursive.

Comment: Path and permissions solved it! Thank you - I changed file path and that solved it. Many thanks.

Comment: Nice to hear that, Hope the answer was useful